# How to pass an url as path param?In JAX-RS @Path

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

http://localhost:8181/RESTfulExample/entityid/https://www.youtube.com

```
@GET
@Path("/entityid/{entityid : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]}")
public Response getUserByentityid(@PathParam("entityid") String entityid) {

    return Response.status(200)
            .entity("getUserByentityid is called, username : " + entityid)
            .build();

}
```

How to modify the regular expression to accept an url in it? Or any other alternate solution to fetch the entityid which is an URL?

Comment: That is not a valid URL.

Comment: that is a valid url if we try to pass entityid = https://www.youtube.com.

Comment: `:` and `/` are not valid characters in a path segment. Even if you allow the `:`, the path would still be parsed as segments: `RESTfulExample`, `entityid`, `https:`, *<empty>*, `www.youtube.com`

Comment: yes you are correct, that's misty only m trying to solve. if we pass https://www.youtube.com,  https: will be accepted as one value as any thing after this '/' will be treated as another value.

Comment: Whoever built that URL didn't encode the path segment. See my answer for an example of correct encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass a URL as a path parameter. Either the entity id is a regular identifier (integer, GUID, ...), in which case it can be in the path like you have it, or it *is* a URL, in which case the URL would be `https://example.com/myapp/entityid/123` and you're back to the entity id *part* of the entity id *URL* being just a regular identifier.

Now, *technically*, you *can* pass a URL as a path parameter by encoding all special characters using [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), however I would not recommend it.

Let's say *your* app is at `https://example.net/otherapp/`, then the combined url would be:

```
https://example.net/otherapp/entityid/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmyapp%2Fentityid%2F123
```

The regular expression would match against the unencoded value, so this might work:

```
{entityid : https?://.*}
```

**NOTE:** Encoding a path segment *must* be done for *all* values, not just for URL value. Integer numbers are safe, but pretty much all other values must be encoded.